How can I programatically start a new session as another user in the same seat
Within a running session (KDE6, wayland) that is locked, from a daemon (KDE Connect), I want to start a session (Gamescope/Steam) as another user and run a streaming software (Sunshine), which needs to have GPU access/lease/something and be able to capture (KMS?) the screen. I do not want to just run Steam as another user within the same desktop session.
The KDE connect user has been started through SDDM quite normally. There is only a single seat. The newly logged in user will take over the seat. The objective is to achieve some isolation, since Sunshine is essentially a remote command tool, and so I don't want to expose my normal user. Containerization and so on is tricky because this is about gaming and sharing a bunch of things and this level of isolation is enough for me, as long as I can lock the normal user. The GPU driver is amdgpu. The target user is a regular one and has a shell (for now) and has succesfully logged in via SSDM/KDE once.
I know that I can su/sudo and run some command to start a plasma session. I believe setsid will figure somehow into this, though I did read somewhere that Wayland sessions don't necessarily care about this.
I'm really lost as to how sddm and whichever Wayland WM communicate to have GPU access or something, and how I can replicate that.
I'm confused as to whether seatd will play a part and what it really does (the manual is short).
I've collected that I'll likely need dbus-run-session as a command wrapper. I'm lost as to whether XDG_* things need to be set, either with new values or inherited from the running session.
After having the session I know I can loginctl and switch to that session.
I think the closest I got was
su -l <user> -c sh -c 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland setsid gamescope -W... -H... --steam -- dbus-run-session steam steam://open/bigpicture' 

However, it seems this session ends up rendering offscreen or something and not having the usual resources. Also I think I didn't manage to programatically switch to this session, and it having screen output is important for the capture AFAIK. Most of the time I get a stuck screen and no output. It has worked once but seemed to be software rendering or had another issue and I started from a separate tty manually.
Bonus: I'd appreciate any pointers to articles that give an overview (not a detailed view of one thing) of how the graphic stacks work so that a WM or game or something gets to use the GPU.
